# after() "сломался" (питон)

Tags: python, tkinter

Писал игру с помощью ткинтер, когда начал делать улучшения столкнулся с проблемой, что второе улучшение должно приносить 1 монету в секунду, но если немножко покликать, то там гораздо больше чем 1 монетка в секунду.

Никак не могу решить эту проблему

```
from tkinter import *

# глобальные переменные
apg = 1 # сколько монет приносит один клик (зависит от апгрейдов)
apg1 = False # куплен ли первый апгрейд
apg2 = False # куплен ли второй апгрейд
clicks = 0 # клики (монеты)




# окно магазина
def open_shop():  
    
    # покупка апгрейда 1
    def kt1():
        global clicks
        global apg1
        if(clicks >= 100 and apg1 == False):
            clicks -= 100
            apg1 = True
            money1['text'] = f'Монет: {clicks}'
        elif(clicks < 100 and apg1 == False):
            messagebox.showerror(title='Ошибка', message='У вас не хватает денег')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(title='Ошибка', message='Вы уже купили этот апгрейд')
        bt1['text'] = 'Куплено'
        
    # покупка апгрейда 2
    def kt2():
        global clicks
        global apg2
        if(clicks >= 350 and apg2 == False):
            clicks -= 350
            apg2 = True
            money1['text'] = f'Монет: {clicks}'
        elif(clicks < 350 and apg2 == False):
            messagebox.showerror(title='Ошибка', message='У вас не хватает денег')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(title='Ошибка', message='Вы уже купили этот апгрейд')
        bt2['text'] = 'Куплено'
    
    # делаем второе окно
    shop = Toplevel(root)
    shop.title('Магазин')
    shop.iconbitmap('Shopping-bag-blue-icon.ico')
    shop.geometry('450x200+370+350')
    shop.resizable(False, False)
    shop['bg'] = '#696969'
    money2 = Label(shop, text=f'Монет: {clicks}',
                   bg='#949399',  fg='#1e2120'
                   )
    # товары в магазине
    t1 = Label(shop, text='клик = 2 монеты',
               bg='#696969', fg='#ebebeb'
               )
    t2 = Label(shop, text='1сек = 1 монета',
               bg='#696969', fg='#ebebeb'
               )
    # кнопки покупки товаров  
    bt1 = Button(shop, text='купить за 100 м.',
                 bg='#949399',  fg='#1e2120',
                 activebackground='#949399', activeforeground='#1e2120',
                 command=kt1
                 )
    bt2 = Button(shop, text='купить за 350 м.',
                 bg='#949399',  fg='#1e2120',
                 activebackground='#949399', activeforeground='#1e2120',
                 command=kt2
                 )
    
    # располагаем элементы на втором окне    
    t1.place(x=10, y=50)
    t2.place(x=130, y=50)
    
    
    bt1.place(x=10, y=70)
    bt2.place(x=130, y=70)
    
    money2.place(x=10, y=10)

# команда для кликов
def click():
    global money
    global clicks
    click_prov()
    clicks += apg
    money1['text'] = f'Монет: {clicks}'
    
# апгрейд 2
def auto_click():
    global clicks, money1
    if(apg2 == True):
        clicks += 1
        money1['text'] = f'Монет: {clicks}'
        root.after(1000, auto_click)

# апгрейд 1
def click_prov():
    global apg
    if(apg1 == True):
        apg = 2
    else:
        apg = 1
    if(apg2 == True):
        auto_click()

# команда для чита
def cheat():
    global clicks
    clicks += 1000

# сновное окно
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x400+345+250')
root['bg'] = '#9C9C9C'
root.title('Кликер')    
root.iconbitmap('Apps-Mouse-icon.ico')
root.resizable(False, False)            

# кнопка открытия магазина
shopb = Button(text='Maгазин',
              command=open_shop,
              bg='#b4b3ba',  fg='#1e2120',
              activebackground='#b4b3ba', activeforeground='#1e2120',
              )

# кнопка для кликов
click = Button(text='кликни',
               command=click,
               width=10, height=2,
               bg='white', fg='#1e2120',
               activebackground='white', activeforeground='#1e2120',
               font='Times 13'
               )
# выводим сколько у пользователя монет
money1 = Label(root, text=f'Монет: {clicks}',
               bg='#b4b3ba',  fg='#1e2120'
               )
# чит
cheat = Button(root, text='клик1000',
               command=cheat
               )

# распологаем все на экране
money1.place(x=10, y=10)      
shopb.place(x=440, y=10)     
click.place(x=197, y=165)
cheat.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста какие действия нужно выполнять и какой результат должен получаться, чем он отличается от текущего, заголовок вопроса - ни о чем, лучше написать ближе к теме вопроса. Суть вопроса чтобы кликать можно было не больше чем раз в секунду?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас при включении функции auto_click(), она вызывается с помощью таймера и по клику, поэтому происходит сбой. Надо, чтоб после запуска таймера она работала только от него. Я сделал это так

```
# апгрейд 2
def auto_click():
    global clicks, money1
#    if (apg2 == True):
    clicks += 1
    money1['text'] = f'Монет: {clicks}'
    root.after(1000, auto_click)


# апгрейд 1
def click_prov():
    global apg, apg2
    if (apg1 == True):
        apg = 2
    else:
        apg = 1
    if (apg2 == True):
        auto_click()
        apg2 = False
```